# How to select two columns from two tables and insert them to single table with two columns

Tags: sql

I used following code but it's not working.

I want to insert the values of `table2.col1` into column1 and values of `table3.col2` into column1 of table1.

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1,column2 ) 
SELECT  col1 FROM    table2 ,
SELECT  col2 FROM    table3
```

Comment: do u have any relation between two tables?

Comment: Use UNION and Temp result table

Comment: It's unclear what the result of that should be. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: `INSERT INTO table1 ( column1, column2 ) SELECT (SELECT col1 FROM    table2) AS column1 , (SELECT  col2 FROM    table3) AS column2`. [Working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c7ea7184a6ca522fbb72f1d94d0e597)

Comment: @Arulkumar: no, not working: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5bb9a951136103cfde766acf0aa9996

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear how you want to merge the data from your source tables into your target table, but here is one approach:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2) 
SELECT col1, NULL 
FROM table2

UNION ALL 

SELECT NULL, col2
FROM table3
;
```

This will copy all rows from `table2` using the `table2.col1` values for `table1.column1` and `NULL` for `table1.column2`.  It will also include all rows from `table3` using `NULL` for `table1.column1` and the `table3.col2` values for `table1.column2`.

This assumes the data types of `table2.col1` and `table3.col2` are the same / compatible.

You may also need to cast the `NULL` values so that the data types match: `CAST(NULL AS <data_type>)`